# SnackBar showing above a certain height when using Coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

So I have the coordinate layout as the root layout as I am using a floating Action button.
Here is my xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        tools:context=".activities.teacher.TeacherJobBoard"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout_job_board"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/color_black_darker_overlay"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/all_night_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".activities.teacher.TeacherJobBoard">

        <com.hugocastelani.waterfalltoolbar.WaterfallToolbar
            android:id="@+id/teacher_job_board_waterfall_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:final_elevation="15dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/teacher_job_board_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/tutor_bear_dark_blue"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

        </com.hugocastelani.waterfalltoolbar.WaterfallToolbar>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/discretescrollview_teacherJobBoard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
        android:id="@+id/spin_kit_job_board"
        style="@style/SpinKitView.Large.WanderingCubes"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        app:SpinKit_Color="@color/color_white" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/extended_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton.Icon"
        android:onClick="expand"
        app:iconSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Filter"
        app:iconPadding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/tutor_bear_dark_blue"
        app:iconTint="@color/white"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_black_darker_overlay"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
<include layout="@layout/bottom_filter_dialog"
    android:id="@+id/filterSheet"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have a simple snack bar in my code like this.

```
Snackbar.make(binding.getRoot(), "This is main activity", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                        }
                    }). show();
```

Problem is when I show the snack bar , it always appears above a certain height from the bottom of the screen. As if there is some kind of a bottom margin set. This only happens when I use coordinate layout.
Snackbar works fine in other layouts.
Picture of the problem is given as a reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the root view instead, `rootLayout_job_board`

```
CoordinatorLayout rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout_job_board);
Snackbar.make(rootLayout), "This is main activity", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    }
                }). show();
```

If that doesn't work, try giving `GRAVITY` using `LayoutParams`

If that doesn't work, also give margins as 0 in LayoutParams.
Also, if your device is Above 9 then you should consider navigation gestures,

`snackbar.isGestureInsetBottomIgnored(false);`
[See here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/BaseTransientBottomBar#isGestureInsetBottomIgnored())

Comment: The coordinate layout is already the root view. binding.getRoot() returns the coordinate layout view.
You mean use gravity like this in the xml attribute of my root layout like this 

android:layout_gravity="bottom"?
tried it,  still doesn't work.

Comment: Not this -> android:layout_gravity="bottom", give gravity programatically by passing through layoutparams while creating snackbar

Comment: Like that ? Or is my code missing something ? Cuz it's still not working

Comment: YES , the gesture did the trick.
snackbar.setGestureInsetBottomIgnored(false); set it to false and it worked. Thankyou

Comment: Happy Coding :)